# Are Bouncers just for IRC?

Tags: proxy, ip

I got to know of a new type of software that allows you to hide your IP address.

[A Bouncer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNC_%28software%29)

Now are bouncers just for the IRC network or can I channel all my internet traffic through it ? If so whats the difference between a bouncer and a proxy ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like bouncers could be considered layer 7 proxies. They manage an application layer connection downstream and provide an application connectivity endpoint upstream. So the proxy itself can stay connected even when the user is not. This could provide a number of services such as logging, notification, and presence even in the face of poor or irregular upstream connectivity.

Most proxies are glorified simple layer 3 routers providing address translation between two domains rather than whole application layer client and server stacks. I think something like squid could be considered a bouncer in the HTTP space even though most HTTP connections are very short lived.

Answer (score 1):

Bouncers are just for IRC.

I'll provide some context on why bouncers were created.  They do hide your IP address but that's not the main reason they were created.

Traditionally, an IRC server is fairly stateless - it passes through messages from senders to receivers, but doesn't hold on to those messages.  It also doesn't maintain persistent records of accounts or channels.  (Modern IRC servers have the idea of services, e.g. NickServ/ChanServ but that wasn't until the 2000s and everyone had broadband).

So let's say you want to have a channel on IRC.  First user to join a channel creates it, and is automatically the channel's operator (chanop).  Chanops can kick users, ban users, set the channel options, or make other users op (and more but keeping it simple).

So if the chanop's network connection to a traditional IRC server dies, and no one else is op, the  channel will be "opless" and no one can do any further kicks or bans.  If everyone leaves a channel, the channel is gone, and then the next person to join it will be automatically op since they are first to join it.

So one reason why a bouncer was created is so you can have a program maintain a connection to an IRC server, keep up on the chat while you are away, and even maintain connections to channels you want to keep up and publicly available (though bots were better for making sure someone in a trusted group always had op privileges).  This mattered a lot in dial-up days - you might have a UNIX account on your school computer or paid shell account.  On there you could run a bouncer, and stay connected to an IRC network.  You can then connect to the bouncer at your convenience over your home dial-up and catch up on chat you may have missed.

This does hide your IP but you don't want to anger your school or shell provider (who can see everything you're doing) so you likely behaved.  (In this situation

You cannot even begin to channel or tunnel much through an IRC server because most IRC servers assume they are being used by humans and have heavy flood control - send more than 4 or 5 lines per second and you'll be throttled, blocked, or banned.

Most things that are called proxies aren't trying to keep a persistent connection on your behalf - e.g. a proxy may accept a connection request from your browser and forward it, but while an IRC bouncer is doing that, it's also staying connected when you detach from the bouncer.